# Атрибут к дочернему элементу jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Доброго времени суток. 
Что нужно, если у label есть класс "active" то input в нутри него присвоить атрибут checked
Попытался реализовать, но что то не то((

```js
$(function() {
  if ($('.new-label').hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

Оно выдает чекед всем инпутам.
Не могу понять как сделать, что бы только дочерний инпут принимал значение.

В примере только один label имеет класс 'active'
Но все инпуты получают checked

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/SkipTyler/pen/YevLRv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $('.new-label').each(function() {
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', $(this).hasClass('active'));
  });
});
```

или

```
$(function() {
  $('.new-label input').prop('checked', false);
  $('.new-label.active input').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! 
Почитаю поподробнее об этих  функциях!

Comment: Без проблем :)
Как только наступит время)